# enabling and disabling accordion with Jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have got an HTML page for my checkout process where i need to enable and disable accordion based on the user inputs.

This is the initially code i got from the UI developer.

```
$(document).ready(function() {
   //ACCORDION BUTTON ACTION    
    $('div.accordionButton').click(function() {
        $('div.accordionContent').not($(this).next()).hide();
              $(this).next('div.accordionContent').slideToggle('normal');
                //$(this).next().slideDown('normal');
     });
});
```

For all disable div/accordion , we are using `accordionButton2` class and once use successfully pass that step, i am changing the class of the `div` so that it should be enable and click function should work.

This is working fine for the first time, but when user is moving ahead, it seems that it is not picking all those div whose class has been changed to `accordionContent` from `accordionContent2`.

It seems to me that it is only picking all those `div` with class set as `accordionContent` on page load and after that it is not picking up anything.

i also tried

```
$('div.accordionButton').bind('click', function() {
```

but seems like it is also not working
How can i achieve this in Jquery, so that i will be able to enable and disable accordion at run time

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
$(document).on('click','div.accordionButton',function() {
        $('div.accordionContent').not($(this).next()).hide();
              $(this).next('div.accordionContent').slideToggle('normal');
                //$(this).next().slideDown('normal');
     });
```

Comment: you mean to say i should remove document.ready and change it to the one suggested by you?